# In Vue3.Parent component use child component's render function, the components registered within the child component are not working

Tags: vuejs3, jsx

In JSX, if custom-component is registered by Child component,and Parent component use Child component's render function to render custom-component. it will report  Failed to resolve component: custom-component

Here is the demo code
Vue version: 3.3.4

child

```
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    customComponent,
  },
  setup(props, ctx) {
       const renderCell = ()=><custom-component />
       //  parent component will get this function
       store.state.renderCell = renderCell
       render(){
          <div>demo</div>
       }
  }
```

parent

```
export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, ctx) {
       const renderCell = store.state.renderCell = renderCell
       render(){
          <div>{{renderCell()}}</div>
       }
  }
```

I noticed in the source code that the issue arises because `currentRenderingInstance` points to the parent component when rendering the custom-component

how should this be resolved?

Comment: seems like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where Y is quite cumbersome. can you give full code for the parent and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev The parent component is trying to access the render functions of different child components stored in the store, and then execute this render function.

Comment: I think the problem is that ()=><custom-component /> is a not standard js syntax its jsx,and it cant be stored in  js (your vuex), so why not using import customComponen